# Use Topic object when communicating with amazon SNS api through mule

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule

I'm using Anypoint Studio to experiment with connectors. At this point, i'm trying to make a simple flow that lists topics available at the amazon SNS endpoint and searches if a certain topic is available.
So far, i'm able to get a response from the API with the list of topics, which i then transform to json using Object to JSON transformer, but i want to iterate through the list to search for a certain topic(using java or whatever filter). The topic entity already exists in the amazon API in Anypoint Studio but i can't find out how to map it to the response returned by the API. Any hint would be appreciated.
EDIT: Here is the code of the flow, removed access keys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sns:config name="Amazon_SNS" accessKey="" secretKey=""  doc:name="Amazon SNS" region="EUWEST1">
    <sns:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</sns:config>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<flow name="CreateTopic">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/createtopic" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:create-topic config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:create-topic-request name="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]"/>
    </sns:create-topic>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Subscribe">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/Subscribe" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:subscribe config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:subscribe-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" protocol="email" endpoint="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.subscriber]"/>
    </sns:subscribe>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="ListTopics">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/listTopics" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:list-topics config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
    </sns:list-topics>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Publish">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/publish" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:publish config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:publish-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" message="There's new content in the topic #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" subject="New comments on an idea - Crowdsourcing Forums" messageStructure="Raw"/>
    </sns:publish>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="checkTopic">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/checkTopic" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:get-topic-attributes config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:get-topic-attributes-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]"/>
    </sns:get-topic-attributes>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message payload you get from `sns:list-topics` is a `com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListTopicsResult`.

So you can use a MEL transformer to filter the topic list with an expression like:

```
($ in message.payload.topics if $.topicArn contains 'my-topic')
```

Reference: [Projections and folds in MVEL 2.0](http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Projections+and+Folds)

Comment: i get the idea, could you please tell me which entity to use? i've tried to use the logger to see if i could retrieve anything from the list but i can't. This is the flow i used:
HTTP -> AmazonSNSListTopics -> Logger
Sorry but i'm kind of a beginner, i'd appreciate any help at all :)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the config in it? I have the impression you're not using http://mulesoft.github.io/sns-connector/mule/sns-config.html#list-topics to get the topics so I really need to see what you're doing to be able to help you.

Comment: i'm merely trying to see the reply of the server, which should be returning a list of topics, but i'm getting this:
Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.transport.NullPayload, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListTopicsRequest, mimeType='*/*'}".

Comment: Not sure why, feels like a bug in the SNS module since your config doesn't do much besides exposing `sns:list-topics` over HTTP...

Comment: That's also what i thought, the connector should serialize automatically the ListTopicsRequest type and send the request to the api, but that's not happening :/